# Is it possible to bend space by force?

Tags: spacetime, curvature, wormholes

I heard that space can be bent by mass, that's not what I'm asking about. My question is, is it possible to bend space directly by applying force?

Example 1:
I took 10 equal plastic rods, and connected them by strings in form of 4d simplex (5 vertices, each vertex is connected to each, by exactly one rod). When I pulled the strings strongly, joining all the joints together, rods bent. That's because 3 dimensional space is too small for equilateral 4 dimensional simplex, so in order to fit into 3D space, my simplex had to deform. If my rods and strings were MUCH stronger, and I applied MUCH more force, is it possible, that instead of bending rods, the space itself would deform?

Example 2:
Let's throw a strong rope into a wormhole, make a knot like a lasso, and pull the rope. Will the space shrink?
[image]

Comment: To create the curvature there no force in Einstein's equations.

Comment: It is worth remembering that general relativity is just a mathematical model. The fact that mathematically spacetime is a 4D "surface" that curves in the presence of mass and energy does not imply that there is some strange 4D fabric that permeates the universe. You can only take the "mass causes spacetime to curve" physical analogy so far.

Comment: Space-time can be bent by mass, but we know famous Einstein equivalence principle between mass and energy : $E=mc^2$. So seems that energy,- including moving object's _kinetic energy_ can bend spacetime too. **Speculation mode ON:** Maybe, just maybe, what's why in quantum mechanics entangled particles feels each other _instantly_, maybe they have some sort of huge interaction energy, which bends space-time and let's information pass instantly between them in some sort of wormhole. **Speculation mode OFF**. I hope not receive critics from speculation part :-D

Answer (score 0):

First it is not space that mass bends, it is spacetime.

Exerting a distinct force will not bend spacetime as an effect, it is more accurate to say that the bending of spacetime *is* a force - the force of gravity. For example the LIGO gravity-wave detector simply detects the effects of the tiny distortions in spacetime which are the gravity waves rippling past.

If you want a rod to bend spacetime, you just have to make the rod extremely heavy. If you loop a cable made of unobtainium through a wormhole it will come out at a very different time from when it went in. If it actually means anything to grasp both ends at the same time, when you pull you will simply tension the cable and not affect the wormhole at all.